# Geolocation: How to calculate the distance from users current location to geocoordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file with data that has the geolocation coordinates for a hospital address.

I want to calculate the distance between the end user's current location and the hospitals address using it's geolocation coordinates.

What the user should see is a list of hospitals, starting with the one that is the closest to them.

So far, I have managed to get a list of hospital data returned back to the user using AJAX. However this also displays the latitude and longitude of the hospital.

I am only using the HTML5 Geolocation API and not Google Maps.

**HTML**

```
<div id="data"></div>
<div id="user"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function loadHospitalData(){
  var url = 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qk08h';
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: 'GET',
  }).done(function(result){
    var data = result.surrey;
    var $data = $('#data');

    data.forEach(function(item){
      var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
      for (field in item) {
        $ul.append(`<li>${item[field]}</li>`)
      }
      $data.append($ul);
    });

    $('#data').replaceWith($data);
    }).fail(function(error){
      console.error(error);
  });
}

loadHospitalData();

// Get user's current location
function getLocation(){
  var x = document.getElementById('user');
  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  }else{
    showError();
  }
  function showPosition(position){
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
  }
}

function showError(error){
  var message;

  switch(error.code){
    case error.PERMISSON_DENIED:
      message.innerHTML = "User denied the request for Geolocation."
    break;
    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
      message.innerHTML = "Location information is unavailable."
    break;
    case error.TIMEOUT:
      message.innerHTML = "The request to get user location timed out."
    break;
    case error.UNSUPPORTED_BROWSER:
      message.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    break;
    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
      message.innerHTML = "An unknown error occured."
    break;
  }
}
getLocation();
```

Here is a JS Fiddle of what I have done so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/1xhebnfs/

JSON data is stored here.

http://myjson.com/qk08h

Any help is much appreciated in advance. THANK YOU!

Comment: Do you want the driving distance or straight-line distance?

Comment: @erjiang great question. I would like the driving distance as straight line distance does not take in the consideration of possible obstacles such lakes or hills that would add on to the Estimated Time of Arrival. Would I need to use the Google Maps API in this case?

Comment: After a bit of googling I found that the Google Maps Distance Matrix API might be my best bet on this.